# Can you have 2 Krita windows open on 2 monitors at the same time showing the same file?

Tags: krita, monitor

Can you have 2 Krita windows open on 2 monitors at the same time showing the same file?

Basically i have a windows tablet device that is a monitor in a drawing position and an ultrawide screen monitor in a heads up position just behind it. I want to be able to see some tools on one display those relevant to mouse and keyboard, and some tools relevant to stylus usage on the tablet whilst editing a single file.

I've achieved a similar setup in blender previously, just wondering if anyone knows any way to make this happen in Krita?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can have two windows of the same file in Krita.
The steps to achieve what you want is:

1. Go to *Window → New Window.* This will open a second window of Krita's interface.
2. Move the newly opened window to your other monitor, then in the new window go to
   *Window → New View* and choose the file that you want in the list.